# Capture user response when using window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to capture whether the user clicked OK or CANCEL?

I need to do something ONLY if the user is leaving the page....

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you (still, in 2014) have to assume that if the window.onunload is fired, then they responded OK to the onbeforeunload question. I've been hoping for something much cleaner, but have yet to find it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution I am using in a situation where I need to do something (such as clear the session) ONLY when the user navigates from the page.

I have 2 global vars

```
var clearSession = true;
var confirmExit = true;


    window.onbeforeunload = function() { return confirmExit(); }
    window.onunload = function() { return clearSession(); }

function confirmExit() {
    if (needToConfirm == true) {       

        return "exit page?";
    }
}


function clearSession() {

     if (clearSession == true) {
        alert("Killing the session on the server!!!");
        PageMethods.ClearSession();
    }
}
```

Then of course, on every page submit/button/drop down list etc...you need to make sure that the above global variables are set to false.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

No, browsers allow you to only specify the text in the alert box, but no way to catch the result.

Comment: oh great, this function is a lot of use then (sarcasm). moving on to onunload

Comment: Either this is completely wrong or I am going insane. I know it's possible to show a confirm dialog on unload; this very site does so if you hit Back while editing a post.

Comment: @gnomixa are you kidding? I'm *glad* browsers don't give this power to the scripting.

Comment: @iandisme: Yes, you can show a confirm dialog, but this is automatically done by the browser (you can only define what text shows up in it). And there is no way to catch the result.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I misunderstood the question. +1 and I'm going to grab another cup of coffee.

Comment: @iandisme You see a dialog, yes, but it's not a `confirm` as in `window.confirm()` dialog.  It's a separate dialog scheme that does not have a readable return value.

Comment: Here's a potential solution: In the function that returns the text for `window.onbeforeunload`, make your ajax call, prepare a modal window, etc. It will be visible the moment they choose to stay on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one setTimeout to verify.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (needToConfirm) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('User still is on the page');
        }, 0);
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
};
```

Basically, the onbeforeunload function blocks the execution and the timeout will only be executed if the user still on the page. The 0 milliseconds is only to put it to the bottom of the execution queue.

Comment: This does the opposite of what was asked in the question. The question was (paraphrased) "How can I get my code to act when the user decides to *leave* the page." The code in your answer acts (raises an alert) when the user *stays* on the page. I'm pretty sure you could fix the code to do what the question actually asks but then what would it be that this method would provide that is better than the method proposed by [sarsnake](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2103974/1906307)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a programming trick or rather a workaround which you can try.
I did not find any "javascript provided" default ways to do it

I have a webpage (it has a form in it) sitting on a local system which needs to be protected from unauthorized users from entering any inputs to it.

I have created a JavaScript function which loads along with loading the main page.

like below

```
<script src="./resources/brazil-uam-all-javascript.js"></script>
  </head>
<body id="uam_gui" onload="authenticate2();">
<div id="UAM_tool">
```

**NOW THE JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION**

The user is supposed to enter a value when prompted with a dialogue box. If the user does not enter any value and simply tries to bypass it by clicking on OK or CANCEL or uses the ESC key or the "Close" button to avoid authentication, then page will bounce back with the same prompt. 
Here I am indirectly capturing the user's response. 
Hope it help's your requirement.

```
function authenticate2() {
var prompt_for_the_magic_number = prompt("Enter Your                         M  A  G  I  C    N  U  M  B  E  R     :::   ", "");
  if (prompt_for_the_magic_number === true)
  {
      if (prompt_for_the_magic_number.length === 0)
      {
          alert("You are supposed to ENTER A VALUE");
          location.reload();
      }
      else
      {
          if (prompt_for_the_magic_number.length > 4)
          {
              alert("You are supposed to ENTER ONLY 4 DIGITS");
              location.reload();
          }
          esle
          {
              //some code to allow access based on a logic
          }
      }
  }
  else
  {
      alert("You are supposed to ENTER 4 DIGITS");
      location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of `beforeunload` event and `unload` event. The idea is to use `beforeunload` event as a way to ask the question before closing the window and to use `unload` event to actually do stuff if the user confirms that he wants to leave the page. Example code in react:

```
const alertUserBeforeExit = useCallback(
(event: { preventDefault: () => void; returnValue: string }) => {
    // prevent and ask the question
    event.preventDefault()
    event.returnValue = ''
},
 []
)

const onExit = useCallback(() => {
  // the answer is yes, do some stuff here
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', alertUserBeforeExit)

 return () => {
   window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', alertUserBeforeExit)
 }
}, [alertUserBeforeExit])

useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('unload', onExit)

 return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('unload', onExit)
 }
}, [onExit])
```