# Question about when user closes browser tab or window

Tags: javascript

I would like to accomplish something like the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    if (confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave the page?")) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

However, the above code does not work, where as even if the user clicks no, the refresh request gets submitted.

How do I accomplish what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also use the `onunload` event which happens *after* the page is unloaded: in case user stay on page it won't get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write confirm inside function:

Try as given below:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function()
{
    return "Are you sure that you want to leave the page?";
}
```

Comment: You're correct about the usage of the basic onbeforeunload, but I think it's the "do something" that he's asking about

Comment: I would like to do something after the user has confirmed to exit, and don't do anything if he decides to stay.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: as jayrdub said _You can't do anything with the "response" of the user to the onbeforeunload prompt..._.Can u explain us yr requirement little bit more so that we can find out any alternate way.

Comment: I have multiple threads open on the server side, and I would like to invalidate them when user is done via AJAX.  The threads cannot be terminated as they will be sleeping, and the server is not keeping state of the sessions. =\

Comment: you can JQuery's ajaxComplete function.in this function you can write yr code after user is complete something via AJAX.[http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything with the "response" of the user to the onbeforeunload prompt...

[Capture user response when using window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103881/capture-user-response-when-using-window-onbeforeunload)

Comment: How does a site like Meebo do it then?  It seems like the site sends AJAX request upon confirmation (hence leading back to authentication page).  Am I misunderstanding something?