# How to know the user response in window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, function

I have written a function which warn a user before refreshing the (I require it for some reason).
What I also want to implement is, call another function if the user clicks on `Leave this page`. If the user clicks on `stay on this page` I have to do nothing.

```
function warnuser()
{
    return "Don't refresh the page.";
}

window.onbeforeunload = warnuser;
//if returns true call another function!
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Check if this is of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103881/capture-user-response-when-using-window-onbeforeunload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user decide to leave the page you can't call functions or anything else, your control is ended...

Answer (score -1):

```
function callbackExit(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //User warned yet he stay on the page.
        //Do your code here now.
    }, 1000);
}   
function warnuser()
{
    callbackExit();
    return "Don't refresh the page.";
}

window.onbeforeunload = warnuser;
```

You can track clicked on "Stay on page" like this, but still you can't perform anything if user click on "Leave site" button.