# jquery onbefore unload trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm using a script to fade out the page content when user is actually leaving the page.

For that I tried using the `beforeunload` event.

It works fine when I navigate through my site, however I also found it triggering on application launch, such as skype button. Even though I never left the page yet...

What is the best way to validate onbeforeunload event against premature triggering?

I guess I should still use my:

```
$(window).one('beforeunload', function() {
  // need to make some condition, if really leaving the page - execute
  $('html.nojs').stop(true,false).css('overflow','hidden').animate({opacity:0},2000);
});
```

But I would need to use some condition... just cannot think of any...

**EDIT:**

*Rmoved the link to the site*

The animation does work, but if you go to any specific product and click skype button there you will see the it makes poo...

**EDIT2:**

The solution to this problem is to detect what triggered an before unload event. As I said, by writing some condition inside that call.

We must find a way to find out whether the event was triggered by external application call (such as skype button that tries to open application) or was it something else, like... for example:( link click, a button submit, script for location change, starting a search, hitting back/forward, or refreshing the page).

Comment: There is no Skype button displayed on your page. Use other PCs to check it. I'm the second one who can't see it!

Comment: It is displayed next to a woman's picture on the right, under the name.

Comment: I see it now. My recommendation, is that you must work more on your current UI rather than animation - Skype button is not seen there, almost at all, among a huge mass of other information and animation makes it only worse. If you want people to buy the UI must be sleek and things must be well seen, especially the contact information. If we couldn't see it - advanced users - then don't expect that the regular folks will. It should be only one second before you really see the Skype button and in your case it's just lost!

Comment: I do understand your remark. This part though is displayed in exactly the same on all the pages, so the folks won't miss it once they'll get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the accepted answer for this question

[Capture user response when using window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103881/capture-user-response-when-using-window-onbeforeunload/2103974#2103974)

If you need to know what triggered the onbeforeunload event, you can have a global variable, then set it to true when you click on the Skype button. Then check it inside your onbeforeload event.

Comment: Do you realize that it triggers when the user already left the page. I mean the animation would not work in that case because it's triggered too late.

Comment: Let's clarify what you are trying to achieve here. You want the animation to work after the user navigated away from the page, correct?

Comment: I think he wants to animate first, delay and then do the rest?

Comment: I want the page to fade out whenever the user clicked the link, or clicked a submit button, or clicked f5, or has been redirected by some script changing the location.href, etc, but want to be certain that he IS leaving this page. The problem is that is till triggers when I click skype button that says 'want to launch the application'? Then the page starts fading even I pressed cancel and stayed on the page.

Comment: I do not intend the delay, the delay naturally happens while the new page is being redirected to is loading. It may be short, or may be long in duration before the next page actually loads, but till then I want the animation to go on.

Comment: Are you refering to the Skype button on your web page? if so, what happens now when you click on your Skype button? What do you mean by "it triggers"?

Comment: I edited my answer, please see the website and see what happens when you click skype button.

Comment: I don't see any Skype buttons on your web page. Am I missing something?

Comment: May be your connection is too fast? It works fine for me in IE, Chrome and FF, just try refreshing the page F5 / ctrl+F5, it does fade out a little bit, while it's loading, then it fades in upon opening.

Comment: nope, no animation.If I were you, I would assign an id to your Skype button and debug what happens when you click on it. It appears to be a button issue rather than beforeunload issue. Capturing user leaving the page is simple and has been done many times using the beforeunload event.

Comment: In particular I would try to find out why clicking on the Skype button triggers beforeunload event.

Comment: So you think this issue is unlikely to occur on other interactions. Then the question is as stated, to find a way of differentiating on what triggered the before unload, and if triggered by skype button cancel the animation. Any ideas how can I make such conditioning?

Comment: Well that's easy. have a global variable, then set it to true when you click on the Skype button. Then check it inside your onbeforeload event.

Comment: Thanks, that IS a way of doing this, and we really get to mutual understanding now :) However, if the user clicked the link, and then wanted to navigate away, how would we return the value to it's initial state? Right now I'm trying to differentiate between the events in this following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288718/jquery-onbefore-unload-trigger#comment16486452_12288718

I've been adviced to log the event, so then I can think of a way of differentiating whether it was triggered by an external application call or no.

Comment: Actually your issue is not that. Since there is no way of stopping the unload event once it's triggered, setting global vars won't help you there and is useless. Your issue is to find out WHY your Skype button is triggering onbeforeunload event.  Are you sure you are not binding it to the button element somewhere in your code?

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Though it proves that onbeforeunload can be stopped at. It triggers beforeunload, however it does not nagvigate to another page.

Comment: I got it solved on the above linked thread. Not without your help, not without your suggestion to bind a variable for `onclick` of the button. You should perhaps also edit your answer to reflect that sane idea of yours :)