# Window unload to trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user navigates away from a page, I want to have them confirm they are leaving the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if($('.fancy-blue-button.check-toggle').text() == 'Check In Task'){
        return 'Note that this task will automatically be checked back in once you leave this page.';
    }
};

$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

The first one, `onbeforeunload` works, the second one, `unload`, does not seem to do anything.

Comment: This didn't help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103881/capture-user-response-when-using-window-onbeforeunload/2103974#2103974

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065085/561731

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - beforeunload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event/16546396#16546396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert will not happen in the `unload` function. You can try to use `console.log`

```
<script>
$(window).unload(function () {
    console.log("Bye!");
});
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gpUfK/)

If you want to call your script using `ajax` you can do it as follows

```
<script>
$(window).unload(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        url: 'scriptUrlGoesHere'
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  change your alert to a console.log and make sure your console doesn't clear on redirect ! Some browsers prevent alerts firing on unload so just make sure it is your unload not working and not the alert due to your browser